# Send multiple rows to one email but send multiple email with row wise

Tags: php, mysql, html

I want to send email with multiple rows from database in php but when I send email that time send multiple email with single row data but I want single email with multiple rows.

I don't know where I am wrong. Below is my running code in php and mysql.

```
$fm_id = $_POST['fm_id'];
$issue = $_POST['issue'];
$resolution = $_POST['resolution'];
$fstatus = $_POST['fstatus'];
$date3= date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
$time2= date("h:i:s");

for ($i = 0; $i < count($fm_id); $i++)
{
    $update=("UPDATE fm_status SET problem='$issue[$i]', solution='$resolution[$i]',status='$fstatus[$i]' WHERE fm_id='$fm_id[$i]'");
    $res=mysql_query($update);

    $update1=("UPDATE fm_status SET  date2='$date3', time2='$time2' WHERE fm_id='$fm_id[$i]'");
    $res1=mysql_query($update1);

    $to ='abc@gmail.com'. ', ';
    $to .='abc@abc.com';

    $subject="Ticket Details from ";
    $header="Solution ";

    $header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $header .= 'From: FM Engineer<solution@abc.com>' . "\r\n" ;

    $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= '<head>';
    $message .= '</head>';

    $message .= "    <align=center>  <div id='apDiv2'>
        <table id='table1' border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='5' class='tinytable cf'>
         <thead>
            <tr>

                <th><h3> Raised By </h3></th>

                <th><h3> Issue </h3></th>
                <th><h3> Resolution </h3></th>
                <th><h3> Status </h3></th>

                </tr> </thead>
        <tbody>

        <td> ".$issue[$i]."</td>             
        <td> ".$issue[$i]."</td>
        <td> ".$resolution[$i]."</td>
        <td> ".$issue[$i]."</td>

        </tr><tbody></table>";

                $message .= '<br>';

    $message .= "</body></html>";

    $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);


    echo $sentmail;
}
```

Comment: (Your post may be easier to read once indented less deeply.)

Comment: 1. **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: If you want to send one email, then append the info to the message in the loop and but send it after. Currently, you're sending one email in each iteration.

Comment: I tried but only single mail send with single row @mangus Eriksson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more along the lines of what you are looking for (I am not going to reiterate the warnings regarding mysql_* functions). If you are trying to add rows to your table to send in one email, then just have the rows built by the for loop like so:

```
$fm_id = $_POST['fm_id'];
$issue = $_POST['issue'];
$resolution = $_POST['resolution'];
$fstatus = $_POST['fstatus'];
$date3= date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
$time2= date("h:i:s");

$to ='abc@gmail.com'. ', ';
$to .='abc@abc.com';

$subject="Ticket Details from ";
$header="Solution ";

$header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'From: FM Engineer<solution@abc.com>' . "\r\n" ;

$message = '<html>';
$message .= '<head>';
$message .= '</head><body>';
$message .= "    <align=center>  <div id='apDiv2'>
    <table id='table1' border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='5' class='tinytable cf'>
     <thead>
        <tr>

            <th><h3> Raised By </h3></th>

            <th><h3> Issue </h3></th>
            <th><h3> Resolution </h3></th>
            <th><h3> Status </h3></th>

            </tr> </thead>
    <tbody>";


for ($i = 0; $i < count($fm_id); $i++)
{
  $update=("UPDATE fm_status SET problem='$issue[$i]', solution='$resolution[$i]',status='$fstatus[$i]' WHERE fm_id='$fm_id[$i]'");
  $res=mysql_query($update);

  $update1=("UPDATE fm_status SET  date2='$date3', time2='$time2' WHERE fm_id='$fm_id[$i]'");
  $res1=mysql_query($update1);

  $message .= "<tr>
          <td> ".$issue[$i]."</td>             
          <td> ".$issue[$i]."</td>
          <td> ".$resolution[$i]."</td>
          <td> ".$issue[$i]."</td>

          </tr>";
}

    $message .= '<tbody></table><br>';

    $message .= "</body></html>";

    $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

    echo $sentmail;
```